# jquery.animateNumber showing millions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the animateNumber plugin to animate a value from zero. However, I have trouble getting a million formatted with dots or commas. That's to say, I need a separator/space bar for my figure but the console shows me the message "Unexpected number" error if I add 2.158.201 or 2 158 201. What is the best way to get it?

Here's my code:

```
function counterFace(){
  var decimal_places = 0;
  var decimal_factor = decimal_places === 0 ? 1 : decimal_places * 10;  
  $('#target-face').animateNumber(
    {
      number: 2158201 * decimal_factor, /* Here I receive an error if I add 2.158.201 or 2 158 201 */

      numberStep: function(now, tween) {
        var floored_number = Math.floor(now) / decimal_factor,
            target = $(tween.elem);
        if (decimal_places > 0) {
          floored_number = floored_number.toFixed(decimal_places);
        }

        target.text(floored_number);
      }
    },
    2000
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please clarify "That's to say, I need a separator/space bar for my figure " and try telling what you need exactly.

Comment: @PierreOcinom On "number" line I can only add 2158201. If I add 2.158.201 or 2 158 201 I receive an "Unexpected number" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand what you are trying to do but this is how you can define a separator for your number :

```
//you can define the separator here
var spaceSeparator = $.animateNumber.numberStepFactories.separator(' ')

$('#target-face').animateNumber(
  {
    number: 2158201,
    numberStep: spaceSeparator
  }
);
```

Just put the separator you want to use between the `('')`.

I strongly suggest you to separate the processing of the stuff you want to input to `animateNumer()` from the method itself. So :

1. Do all the stuff you need to input (`function(now, tween)` and `2158201 * decimal_factor`)and assign it to variables.
2. Use this variables in `animateNumbers()`

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know where to add that code but with your advices it's all right.